# Changing remote tracking branches in git(-svn) after clone with restricted branches

Tags: git, git-svn

When restricting remote branches to a list of 2 or three (editing the .git/config as seen in {^1}), refetching, carbage collectioning and cleaning all "refs" directories I still get a full list of all remote branches with `git branch -avv` {^2}

I expected to see v2 and v3 only as branches in the list of remote branches.
Any ideas how to fix this? Or is that the "git way" to present all remote branches either we might work with or not?

{^1}

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
url = https://example.com/svn/repos/MyRepo/SubPath
fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
branches = branches/{v2,v3}:refs/remotes/*
```

{^2}

```
* master         1234 [trunk: ahead 1] last msg master
  remotes/v1     2345 last msg svn branch v1
  remotes/v2     3456 last msg svn branch v2
  remotes/v3     4567 last msg svn branch v3
  remotes/v4     5678 last msg svn branch v4
  remotes/trunk  6789 last msg svn trunk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git branch -D -r remotes/v1 remotes/v4 remotes/trunk
rm -rf .git/svn/refs/remotes/{v1,v4,trunk}
```

Comment: Thank you for that hint. Deleting them will prune it, so rm of refs is not needed as far as I can see / test.